# A python program that opens a PDF file and copy a specific line from it and after close and rename the PDF with a copied line

Tags: python, pypdf, administration

I must rename a number of PDF files with the serial numbers of laptops every day as part of my routine. I need somekind of a script/software that opens a PDF file, copies a certain line (service tag) from it, then closes and renames the PDF with the copied serial number from it.

I tried to use the PyPDF2 package in Python, but my code is  not working.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


reader = PdfReader("SNPDF.pdf")

page = reader.pages[0]
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)

text = page.extract_text()



for x in text:
    if x.startswith("SN"):
        new_name = x.replace("SN", '')
      


print(new_name)
```

It worked with .txt file, but I have no clue how to run it with PDF.

```
import os

serial = open('text.txt')
for line in serial:
    if line.startswith("SN"):
        new_line = line.replace('SN','')

serial.close()

os.rename('text.txt', new_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `PyMuPDF` package is better,you need to import the "fitz" package to use it,

```
pdf_file = "SNPDF.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
for page in doc:
    text = page.get_text()
    if text.startswith("SN"):
        new_name = text.replace("SN", '')
doc.close()
```

Comment: as [911](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17125527/911) wrote: should be easy to do with PyMuPDF - but see my suggested code below.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should extract the service tag from the first page of the PDF file and rename the file with the extracted service tag.

```
import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

FILE_TO_RENAME = "SNPDF.pdf"
SERVICE_TAG_PREFIX = "SN"

with open(FILE_TO_RENAME, "rb") as f:
    reader = PdfReader(f)
    # Replace "0" with the index of the page that contains the service tag
    page = reader.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

# Search for the service tag in the extracted text
for line in text.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith(SERVICE_TAG_PREFIX):
        service_tag = line.partition(SERVICE_TAG_PREFIX)[2].strip()
        break
else:
    raise Exception(f"No service tag prefix found: {SERVICE_TAG_PREFIX}")

# Rename the PDF file with the service tag
os.rename(FILE_TO_RENAME, service_tag + ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF package

pdfnames = [...]  # list of pdf pathnames

for f in pdfnames:
    doc = fitz.open(f)
    page = doc[0]  # load first page
    words = page.get_text("words")  # extract text separated as strings w/o spaces
    SN = None
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word[4] == "SN"  # search for SN identifier
            SN = words[i+1][4]  # next word string should be serial number
            break
    if SN == None:
        print(f"no SN in file '{f}'.")
        continue
    doc.close()  # close the file for renaming it
    os.rename(f, SN + ".pdf")
```